# Is it possible to setup TFS proxy server with a VPN connection?

Tags: tfs, proxy

Is it possible to setup TFS proxy server with VPN connection?. We are in need of setting up a TFS proxy server at our local network by connecting to client network. The only option we have is to connect to client network is through VPN.

Being connected to VPN how does local TFS Proxy server communicate with remote TFS Server.
What are all the required network connection/communications need to set.

Comment: Do you have a site to site vpn, or does each developer connect to the vpn manually on their box?

Answer (score 1):

A TFS Proxy server requires the following things:

- It must be able to connect to the main TFS server. This is usually HTTP traffic to port 8080 on the TFS server.
- It must be running as a Windows account that has access to TFS. This means that it needs to be installed on a machine that is in the same domain as the TFS server (or a trusted domain)*

So, in your scenario - as long as the VPN connection is dialled automatically by the TFS Proxy server, or you're using a site-to-site VPN appliance, then everything should be sweet.

**In TFS 2010 Proxy, you can run it on a machine that is in a totally unrelated domain by using 'Shadow Accounts'. Shadow Accounts are where you create a local user account on the proxy server that has a matching username/password to an account in the TFS Server's domain.*