# Point Visual Studio at TFS on another domain

Tags: tfs, cross-domain

Is there a way for our development team to point Visual Studio at an instance of TFS on another domain?

Pretty green when it comes to Team Foundation Server and not sure if this should go in the overflow that handles IT admin stuff (from my understanding stackoverflow is more code related).

We just got bought by another company and they want us to use their TFS that resides on their domain. We are working on getting to one domain, but in the mean time we still have two separate domains that talk enough to get by.

Comment: Is there a trust relationship between the domains? As long as there is, there's no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Daniel said, just make sure there is a trust relationship between the domains.

Generally if you can access the TFS that resides on another domain with you current domain user, then everything should be OK.

More information please see [Trusts and Forests Considerations for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms253081(v=vs.100)) and [Grant the Allowed to Authenticate permission on computers in the trusting domain or forest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc738653(v=ws.10)) for details.

You can also reference this related thread : [TFS Cross-domain authentication without trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012701/tfs-cross-domain-authentication-without-trust)